# Upon changing http to https google signin not working

Tags: laravel, google-signin, google-plus-signin

While installing certificate i.e. changing HTTP to HTTPS of my domain, Google login fails to redirect to the given redirect URL. But the login is successful, still, google results error ("400. That’s an error.The requested URL was not found on this server. That’s all we know").
I have changed the redirect url in google api credentials to 'https'.

[image]

Comment: Do you have an entry for https in your "Authorized redirect URIs" located at https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials under the credentials link?

Comment: @MichaelMiller Yes. Login is successful too, but not redirecting to my domain. Instead, it shows the error I mentioned in the question.

Comment: Where is the URL "https://accounts.google.co.in/accounts/SetSID#" coming from?

Comment: @MichaelMiller On giving my google account details and clicking "Sign In", the page is redirected to this URL.

Comment: Let me see if I can rephrase that...  If you're to run a search over your code, where does "accounts.google.co.in/accounts/SetSID" show up?